# Changing docker image throws: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFile: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-3" error

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, postgis

I am running a dockerized django application with a postgres database that has postgis installed. I am using the official image for that and I build it with docker-compose like so:

```
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_postgis
    image: postgis/postgis
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
```

That worked well. Now I am trying to change this image with the official timescale image that has postgis installed as well (https://hub.docker.com/r/timescale/timescaledb-postgis/). I am changing my docker-compose file like this:

```
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_postgis_timescale
    image: timescale/timescaledb-postgis:latest-pg12
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
```

My app builds fine and runs fine, but when I try to access data that use postgis I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-3": No such file or directory
```

So I entered my database and tried to upgrade the extension with `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;` but I get `extension "postgis" has no update path from version "3.0.1" to version "2.5.3"` , so I guess I am up to date.

I am quite sure it is connected to this extension but have no idea how I could fix this... Anyone might be able to help me out?

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: What is odd that that both images have the same extension-version:

```
          Name          | Version |   Schema   |                             Description                             
------------------------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 fuzzystrmatch          | 1.1     | public     | determine similarities and distance between strings
 plpgsql                | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis                | 3.0.1   | public     | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
 postgis_tiger_geocoder | 3.0.1   | tiger      | PostGIS tiger geocoder and reverse geocoder
 postgis_topology       | 3.0.1   | topology   | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions
```

When I go back to the old image it works again....

Comment: Have you checked that both images have the same version of Postgres? It is possible that datafiles that are persisted via `local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data` volume are not compatible. Try recreating database files using new image.

Comment: Thanks jazgot! I will check the postgres version, thanks for that. With recreating the DB-files you mean I should delete all that I have and set create it from scratch?

Comment: What I mean is try to recreate docker volumes, this can be done using `docker-compose down -v` and then `up` again.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, will try and post the results!